# Pseudo Code for Producer Consumer Synchronization

Tags: c, semaphore, pseudocode

I'm having some trouble writing Pseduocode for a homework assignment in my operating systems class in which we are programming in C.

> You   will    be  implementing    a   Producer-Consumer   program with    a    bounded    buffer  queue   of  N   elements,   P   producer    threads and C   consumer    threads 
>   (N, P   and C   should  be  command line    arguments   to  your    program,    along   with    three    additional parameters, X,  Ptime   and Ctime,  that    are described   below).     **Each
>
>   Producer    thread  should  Enqueue X   different numbers   onto    the queue   (spin-waiting    for    Ptime*100,000 cycles    in  between each    call    to  Enqueue).       Each    Consumer    thread
>
>   should  Dequeue P*X/C   items   from    the queue   (spin-waiting   for Ctime*100,000 cycles
>   in  between each    call    to  Dequeue).**         The main    program should  create/initialize   the 
>   Bounded Buffer  Queue,  print   a   timestamp,  spawn   off C   consumer    threads &   P
>   producer    threads,    wait    for all of  the threads to  finish  and then    print   off another 
>   timestamp   &   the duration    of  execution.

My main difficulty is understanding what my professor means by spin-waiting for the variables times 100,000. I have bolded the section that is confusing me.

I understand a time stamp will be used to print the difference between each thread. We are using semaphores and implementing synchronization at the moment. Any suggestions on the above queries would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it means busy-waiting; repeatedly checking the loop condition and consuming unnecessary CPU power in a tight loop:

```
while (current_time() <= wake_up_time);
```

One would ideally use something that suspends your thread until it's woken up externally, by the scheduler (so resources such as the CPU can be diverted elsewhere):

```
sleep(2 * 60 * 1000 ms);
```

or at least give up *some* CPU (i.e. not be *so* tight):

```
while (current_time() <= wake_up_time)
    sleep(100 ms);
```

But I guess they don't want you to manually invoke the scheduler, hinting the OS (or your threading library) that it's a good time to make a context switch.

I'm not sure what **cycles** are; in assembly they might be CPU cycles but given that your question is tagged C, I'll bet that they're simply loop iterations:

```
for (int i=0; i<Ptime*100000; ++i); //spin-wait for Ptime*100,000 cycles
```

Though it's always safest to ask whoever issued the homework.

Comment: Damn good answer... However: it's safe to assume that nobody understands the question, ESPECIALLY the professor who asked it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**busy-waiting** or **spinning** is a technique in which a process repeatedly checks to see if a condition is `true`, such as whether keyboard input is available, or if a lock is available.

so the assignment says to wait for **Ptime*100000** time before producing next element and enqueue x different elements after the condition is **true**

similarly Each Consumer thread
should Dequeue `P*X/C` items from the queue and wait for ctime*100000 after every consumption of item

Comment: I read "spin-waiting for Ptime*100,000 **cycles**", which I interpret as literal "processing cycles" aka "clock ticks"... i.e. not "time".

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your professor is being a complete putz - by actually ASKING for the worste "busy waiting" technique in existance:

```
int n = pTime * 100000;
for ( int i=0; i<n; ++i) ; // waste some cycles.
```

I also suspect that he still uses a pterosaur thigh-bone as a walking stick, has a very nice (dry) cave, and a partner with a large bald patch.... O/S guys tend to be that way. It goes with the cool beards.

No wonder his thoroughly modern students misunderstand him. He needs to (re)learn how to grunt IN TUNE.

Cheers. Keith.